# Is it possible to schedule a maven jar file from Google Cloud Storage in Cloud Task?

Tags: node.js, executable-jar, google-cloud-tasks

I am new to Google Cloud Platform.I am trying to schedule a maven jar uploaded in Google Cloud Storage in Google Cloud Task using NodeJS.

I am unable to find any help on how to do this, is it possible to schedule a maven jar file for such a case?

Comment: Hello, can you provide more information about your use case. What to you mean by scedueling a maven jar file ?

Comment: Hi marian, I meant can we pass maven jar file from GCS  as a request/payload for the task and add in the queue?

Comment: Hello, could you please specify the end use case of the jar file and elaborate further on why you need it in the payload of the Cloud Tasks? Is it some kind of Library needed for the execution of your application code?

Comment: Artemis, actually the maven file is a Apache beam  jar file and I have to pass the path of the jar file in the task api so that the job can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible per now to pass the jar file in the Cloud Tasks API, as this pipeline seems little bit confusing.

To achieve your goals, you can do trigger a Cloud Function from Google Cloud Storage when there are modifications in the Cloud Storage file (either by upload, etc), and then create a HTTP Cloud Task inside the Cloud Function to do what you want. You can also set a scheduled time in the future when you want to execute your task or the number of times you want the task to be retried if it fails.

You can follow the next steps:

1. Create a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console).
2. [Trigger the Cloud Function where there is a change or modification to your Cloud Storage file](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage).
3. In the Cloud Function, create a [HTTP Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#node.js).

Please let me know if it works for you.